# Past life memories: what is the purpose of those memories?

Tags: past-lives

As a child I remembered being born, being in the womb, and the death that preceeded this birth.

I recalled the time between the death and the womb.

I recalled the act I dying.

I recalled the act of taking a blade to my own throat and the process of dying.

I still recall many of the things I did which caused suffering in my previous life, but I do not recall those whom I helped, or loved.

It is a heavy load to bear. Is there a purpose to this ? Am I meant to work to relieve the same suffering I caused in others ?

---

"Danuka Shewantha asked (2018-03-07): If you don’t mind can you explain your experience with us. Are you recalling past life memory?"

Being born:
Very young I had a recurring nightmare, and it would follow me when I woke up. It was a dream of being huge in a small space and suddenly extremely small in an infinite space. The size of the space I came to realize was being defined by being squeezed from all sides and then the contact disappearing. When all the surface of my skin was in contact with the "squeezing" it felt like I was a giant and the space around me was too small for me, it panicked me, and then when the surface in contact with my skin withdrew I felt myself floating without any sense of being touched -therefore I had no size, it felt like being infinitely small in an infinitely large space. This felt like relief.

This is what I later came to understand (perhaps wrongly, but it felt correct), as the memory of being born. The squeezing of the uterus against me, and then, when the contraction subsided, the feeling of the liquid around and no contact. When I was young I asked other children if they had the same nightmare and several told me they had it too. The memory of it seems to fade, like all nightmares.

My suicide:
One day a friend of one of my aunts, in a (very successful) effort to endear himself gave me a present for Easter (I was raised in a Catholic home). It was a huge rabbit standing like a person. It was wearing clothes like a person (a blazer and short pants). He was taller than I was.  I would have been maybe 6 (?), not much older (we moved from that house when I was 7), but maybe younger. The rabbit was upstairs, there was a downstairs play area in this house. 
There was a moment when everything went black (no sight memory, just missing time). Then I felt like I was in a different place. I ran to the kitchen and in the utensil drawer I dug through the knives. I looked at them and kept touching them to find the one my hand remembered. I chose a short knife with a wooden handle. The knife had been washed so much the wood was rough, but it had once been smooth, the wood felt weathered, like the outside wood of an unpainted house. The surface changed by the rain. The blade of the knife had been sharpened many times on a stone. It was a knife my mother used in the vegetable garden, so my father sharpened it regularly because it was often made dull by the labour. I recall the blade shape, but I don't know how to describe it. I recall the knife as clearly as if it were before me now. I can see the lines from the sharpening reflecting light, the colour of the handle. The small rivets that held the wood to the blade were blackened. I held the knife in my hand, the butt of the handle against the middle of my palm.

I knew the knife as familiar in that moment because of the place the handle fit into my palm, the length of it. It was "correct". I ran downstairs with the knife. I leaned the rabbit against a door frame to hold it vertical. Standing in front of it I looked for the place in its neck, and I sliced into it with the knife. 
At that moment everything went black. I felt myself different. I felt my right arm, pressed against my body, reaching for my neck on the left side, and the knife in my hand. I felt the tip of the blade against my skin. I felt the moment before the blade cut into my flesh as the blade pushed, and then the moment the skin broke. The flood of heat of my blood flowing from the wound. I felt the heat of the blood as it poured over my skin. I felt the pushing, pulsing of my heart, beating loud, and the increasing heat of the blood as my skin became cold. It (felt as though) it burned my skin. I felt everything. My eardrums hurt as though there was such a huge silence my heartbeat was crushingly loud. The memory continues from that, but I don't know if you really want to know what happened afterwards. It was quite horrible. 
Before birth:
I recalled from that event forward and being sent into the womb. I recalled that someone/something sent me, like being pushed by a voice. As though the voice were wind and I was dust.  There were many voices, not all agreed with my birth. Someone advocated for me. I did not have voice. I did not speak, I listened, involved, but not desirous (not against either) the outcome.

when the vision broke I awakened on the ground, next to the now 'dead' rabbit, the small styrofoam pellets all over the floor. I could not explain to my mother why I had destroyed such a lovely gift which I loved so much. She thought it ungrateful of me. Which it was, in many ways.

There are many other such moments. I recall being widowed (that pain is still searing now). I recalled my attachment to wealth and what I did to amass it. I recall the pain I brought to others through my actions, and I recall their blaming me for their suffering. I have met many of them in my life now, and I see them act on the experiences we shared. I see them continue to struggle with the experiences, but they don't seem to recall them. They are just blindly acting on the pain. Some I have helped, but many are living in a fog. It is very like watching a person you knew as a child and knowing the reasons for their current actions is their past experience.

---

"Sankha Kulathantille asked (2018-03-08): Do you remember the names of your parents in the past life or at least the place they stayed?

That is an interesting question, I never wondered about the names of parents. I chastised myself severly for not recalling the names of my children, but parents never occured to me.

I recall young being very upset to be called by the name which I was given. I could not understand why they called me that and it upset me greatly. I knew it wasn't my name and I concentrated very hard to recall my real name. The name I have now is Michele, and when I focused I could recall my name as something very different that I had never heard before. It was something like Mishcoot. I tried to reason with myself that the first part of the name sounded like the first part of this name and it should not be so important. I cried myself to sleep and each time my name bothered me I reminded myself it was not so different. I am still uncomfortable with my name and I avoid its use as much as I can. I try not to think about what I lost. "My name" now is not mine, it is just what people call me. I know when I hear it that I am being addressed, but I feel no attachment to it. It could just as easily be a sound like a whistle or a grunt.

Where:
(very young) I cried inconsolably at the sight of Jewish cemeteries and when asked I explained I could not be buried on sacred ground. I was raised Roman Catholic in a homogenous area, and had never met anyone Jewish at that time.

When I was first in school and learning letters I kept insisting that they also had a numeric value and words could be added. Frustrated teachers insisted I was wrong and to stop insisting. It would be decades before I learned that Hebrew does this.

The first time I traveled to NYC (New York city USA) I knew where things were without maps or street names. I ran down a street and closed my eyes as I reached a street corner. With eyes closed I (gleefully) lifted my left arm and pointed. With eyes still closed I said "Grand Central Station" and when I opened my eyes it was there. It wasn't a surprise, it just was where I knew it would be. I continued this game that first day, and then I just settled into the familiarity. It was very pleasant, and it felt safer there than anywhere else. Like a well loved child in their familial space.

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain your experience with us. Are you recalling past life memory?

Comment: Do you remember the names of your parents in the past life or at least the place they stayed?

Comment: @danukashewantha I answered above. Please let me know if I should modify or delete, I am unfamiliar with protocols. I am concerned that my answer may be too much. If the goal (for everyone) is to let go, should I not hide this information in order not to draw others or myself into a spiral of focusing on the past ? thank you for your guidance

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille I answered above. Please let me know if I should modify or delete. I am unfamiliar with protocols. thank you for your guidance.

Comment: @Mishtook Thanks! It's not against protocol. It's very interesting information, if you are genuinely telling the truth. Did you try to connect with descendants of your previous family or relatives?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille I feel great shame for what I did. My life is one of exile. I live alone in a cabin in the mountains. I come to the city 3 days a week to work, but I have no contact with people other than that. I do not communicate with any relatives (current or past).

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille  I worked for a time for an older man whom I eventually discovered had lost his mother to suicide. I wondered if he and his sister might have been my children. They were born in NYC and were Jewish. I did not ask the circumstances of her death. I worked for him for 8 years, he was a good person, as was his sister. They were very close to each other, but the two halves of their family were split. Their mother's family blamed their father for the death, and the father took them away. They went more than 60 years without knowing their mother's family because of her suicide.

Comment: @Mishtook Don't be ashamed. The Samsara is beginningless. We have all committed suicide in the past. What you take as 'I','me' or 'mine' are mere moments of experiences that arise and pass away without your control. it's all a process of causes and effects. There's nothing there to be taken as 'myself'.

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille would there not be responsibility to those who suffered from your actions ? is that not the reason we feel (and cultivate) empathy and compassion? If I understand, is karma the resultant of actions, but measured in impact on others ? if i swing my arm and there is only air (no karma), or if there is a person struck and hurt by the movement (bad karma), or there is a flying object which would have struck a person, but is interrupted and the person is saved from being harmed (but my arm is hurt in this act), then good karma ?

Comment: @Mishtook No! Karma is very different to what you think. Karma is the intention. Ex: If you accidentally step on an ant, the ant will die. The result of your action  caused a death. But it is not bad Karma for you as long as you did not intend to harm the ant. There's bad Karma and there is good Karma. Any hateful, greedy or ignorant intention is bad Karma. Any non-hateful, non-greedy and non-ignorant intention is good Karma except in the case of Arahanths. We can talk about responsibility of actions on a conceptual level, but at the ultimate level there are no beings.

Comment: It's only experiences arising and ceasing. As far as responsibility goes, it's merely a case of wholesome intentions resulting in pleasant experiences and unwholesome intentions resulting in unpleasant experiences. But it's still just experiences arising and ceasing. There's no self in any of them.

Comment: Compassion is cultivated to counter cruel intentions as it will result in unpleasant experiences. Cruelty also hinders the path to enlightenment

Comment: @Mishtook, it's a long and description of your personal experience and thanks very much for it. I will read and analyze closely. I must tell you, I am little bias to rationalism and science. But I am humble not to refuse concepts like rebirth and other Buddhist concepts. My suggestion to you is stay with us(Buddhist community in this site or any other) and share your knowledge and experiences and continue the journey and gain more and more wisdom to find the path. The beauty of this community is having and confronting different opinions and holding various prospective and lead ....

Comment: ....a very fruitful discussions valuable to readers and participators of this site. I am still questioning the Buddhism without any hesitations just  for reach the path.(as a humble learner) your honest  personal experience is so unique and valuable to this site. Thanks for your respond and stay with us. Metta!

Comment: @danukashewantha thank you for your kindness and warmth. I am also (very) biased towards what should (in my case)be labeled doubt. I look always for proof that things are not so, and no matter how many times I fail to disprove, I still do not find it to be truth. I am afflicted with often knowing things before they arise, or knowing things about others, but no matter how often it is confirmed by outside source I always reserve trust. I wonder if I somehow gleaned it from available information or the person is agreeing because it soothes them to do so. I keep looking for a rational explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I think in this case the purpose is for you to have a readymade insight in dukkha and rebirth. With your knowledge niw you know that if you dont strive for enlightenment you are now bound for another birth again suffering. You insight should help you go deep into meditation. Realise the insight of impermenance.

You are not meant to relieve any thing from past, what you are meant is to realise annata i.e. there is no self to be found anywhere. And hence get relieved from suffering once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no purpose to *anything* (other than purposeful acts, by definition). My teacher specifically emphasized this point as very important. Until we realize *there is no purpose to life* we can't accept spontaneous suchness.

There are bits and pieces of information floating in this ocean of energy that manifests as existence and life. This information is no one's. It is not me and not you, but it is what sustains notions of "me" and "you". Some of the information gets recycled in various ways and becomes material for building new forms of existence (new lives).

Identifying with this information is one of the most fundamental delusions that causes suffering and new karma that leads to suffering. Identification leads to taking sides, or to feelings of guilt etc.

Instead, Buddha's advice is to consider nothing as "me" or "mine". By letting go of self-identification we let go of suffering.

At the same time, any circumstances we are given at birth are a blessing. Whatever we have, a talent or a handicap or some difficult life situation, is always something that connects us with our life's mission - whether we want it or not! So in this sense, your memories are "meant" to be used as a starting point for your life's journey - absolutely and without a doubt.

Depending on your age it may not be the time for you to know this clearly yet, which exact way it connects, but one day you'll know. I can't give away the answer to puzzle that is your life, because it is only yours to assemble.

The only piece of advice I can give is to never compromise with your sense of belonging, always go after what you want most (in the high sense, not savage stuff, you know what I mean), and never tolerate a lukewarm existence just out of fear of change. Step by step this will form into the path that you're meant to have.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of recollecting past lives is described in the [Khajjaniya Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.079.than.html):

> "Monks, any brahmans or contemplatives who recollect their manifold
>   past lives all recollect the five clinging-aggregates, or one among
>   them. Which five? When recollecting, 'I was one with such a form in
>   the past,' one is recollecting just form. Or when recollecting, 'I was
>   one with such a feeling in the past,' one is recollecting just
>   feeling. Or when recollecting, 'I was one with such a perception in
>   the past,' one is recollecting just perception. Or when recollecting,
>   'I was one with such mental fabrications in the past,' one is
>   recollecting just mental fabrications. Or when recollecting, 'I was
>   one with such a consciousness in the past,' one is recollecting just
>   consciousness.
>
> "And why do you call it 'form'? Because it is afflicted, thus it
>   is called 'form.' Afflicted with what? With cold & heat & hunger &
>   thirst, with the touch of flies, mosquitoes, wind, sun, & reptiles.
>   Because it is afflicted, it is called form.
>
> "And why do you call it 'feeling'? Because it feels, thus it is called
>   'feeling.' What does it feel? It feels pleasure, it feels pain, it
>   feels neither-pleasure-nor-pain. Because it feels, it is called
>   feeling.
>
> "And why do you call it 'perception'? Because it perceives, thus it is
>   called 'perception.' What does it perceive? It perceives blue, it
>   perceives yellow, it perceives red, it perceives white. Because it
>   perceives, it is called perception.
>
> "And why do you call them 'fabrications'? Because they fabricate
>   fabricated things, thus they are called 'fabrications.' What do they
>   fabricate as a fabricated thing? For the sake of form-ness, they
>   fabricate form as a fabricated thing. For the sake of feeling-ness,
>   they fabricate feeling as a fabricated thing. For the sake of
>   perception-hood... For the sake of fabrication-hood... For the sake of
>   consciousness-hood, they fabricate consciousness as a fabricated
>   thing. Because they fabricate fabricated things, they are called
>   fabrications.
>
> "And why do you call it 'consciousness'? Because it cognizes, thus it
>   is called consciousness. What does it cognize? It cognizes what is
>   sour, bitter, pungent, sweet, alkaline, non-alkaline, salty, &
>   unsalty. Because it cognizes, it is called consciousness.
>
> **"Thus an instructed disciple of the noble ones reflects in this way:
>   'I am now being chewed up by form. But in the past I was also chewed
>   up by form in the same way I am now being chewed up by present form.
>   And if I delight in future form, then in the future I will be chewed
>   up by form in the same way I am now being chewed up by present form.'
>   Having reflected in this way, he becomes indifferent to past form,
>   does not delight in future form, and is practicing for the sake of
>   disenchantment, dispassion, and cessation with regard to present form.**
>
> **"[He reflects:] ''I am now being chewed up by feeling... perception...
>   fabrications... consciousness. But in the past I was also chewed up by
>   consciousness in the same way I am now being chewed up by present
>   consciousness. And if I delight in future consciousness, then in the
>   future I will be chewed up by consciousness in the same way I am now
>   being chewed up by present consciousness.' Having reflected in this
>   way, he becomes indifferent to past consciousness, does not delight in
>   future consciousness, and is practicing for the sake of
>   disenchantment, dispassion, and cessation with regard to present
>   consciousness.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you remember that is because it is a very strong memory.

You should feel lucky to be able to remember something about your past life, even though it is a very unpleasant memory. Many people take up materialistic/nihilistic views just because they have no memory of their past lives. They waste their whole life thinking up materialistic theories and sinking deep into ignorance to justify the belief that it's all over at death.

Like other answerers have mentioned, there's no purpose to anything in life. You are not supposed to do anything. But you can certainly use this memory to your advantage to cultivate your mind so that you do not have to experience such horrors ever again.

Answer (score 1):

So I have thought to give some reasonable and rational answer to your issue. I will not push you to mystery or darkness with my answer. First of all our (human) brain include 100 billion neuron cells and trillions of electro-chemical activities called "functional brain or stream of mind" create lot of illusions and dilutions we totally failed to understand and interpret. Our mind is a the great creator of everything. When I state everything it include our mind. So this is a one whole system. I have similar(small compare to yours) paranormal experience and I have realized it as distorted brain function. Your paranormal experience is so strong. When you come to mind it create illusion of me,mine,I and lead to lots of trouble. I suggest to you engage with meditation suitable to you like Zen or any other. Try to live and stay in present. Don't try to live in past. Try to convince mind using same mind what you recall is past event and that's an illusion. conquer the mind and become a great conqueror. you have to confront a grate battle with mind and it require lots of courage.If you require further explanations please do not hesitate to communicate. hope my suggestions will help you. Thanks and metta!

Comment: is there a way to have a private exchange on this site ? I have a question.

Comment: There's no privacy (hidden from moderators) on the site. You can use a chat room [e.g. this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism), or exchange email addresses (post your email address so the other person can email you).

Comment: you can forward mail danuka5870213@gmail.com. Thanks